# Swift function showing compile error "ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Why is this Swift function requiring more context now?  This shows up on the line with `.CurveLinear`

```
func playSequence(index:Int,highlightTime:Double){
    currentPlayer = .Computer

    if index == inputs.count{
        currentPlayer = .Human
        return
    }

    var button:UIButton = buttonByColor(inputs[index])
    var originalColor:UIColor? = button.backgroundColor
    var highlightColor:UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(highlightTime,delay: 0.0,options: .CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState,
        animations:{
            button.backgroundColor = highlightColor
        }, completion: {
            finished in button.backgroundColor = originalColor
            var newIndex:Int=index+1
            self.playSequence(newIndex, highlightTime: highlightTime)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2 syntax for multiple options requires an option set in square brackets. In your animateWithDuration you need to create an option set:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(highlightTime,delay: 0.0,options:[.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState],
        animations:{
            button.backgroundColor = highlightColor
        }, completion: {
            finished in button.backgroundColor = originalColor
            var newIndex:Int=index+1
            self.playSequence(newIndex, highlightTime: highlightTime)
    })
```

You can also define a set explicitly like this:

```
let mySet : UIAnimationOptions = [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState]
```

Comment: Compile errors went away! They shy away from commenting thanks but hopefully you get where I'm going with this :)